# Transform XSL nodes to comma separated html attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

My source XML is something like this:

```
<data>
 <capability>Sound Design</capability>
 <capability>Video Production</capability>
 <capability>Web Design</capability>
</data>
```

I would like to transform it via XSL to get a result like so:

```
<header data-capabilities="Sound Design, Video Production, Web Design">
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using xslt 2.0, you can use something like:

```
<xsl:template match="data">
    <header>
        <xsl:attribute name="data-capabilities">
            <xsl:value-of select="*" separator=", "/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </header>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Or even shorter with the `separator` defined directly on `xsl:attribute` e.g. `<xsl:attribute name="data-capabilities" select="capability" separator=", "/>`: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-attribute